# How can I compare only hour and minute in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column stop_execution_date in sysjobactivity table. I need to get details of job only which ran after 4:10 AM.

I tried it using

```
    cast(DATEPART(hour, sja.stop_execution_date) as varchar)+cast(DATEPART(minute, sja.stop_execution_date) as varchar) >410
```

But, if job completes at 9:05 AM it is not accepting because datepart(hour) is 9 and datepart(minute) is 5. By using + we are getting 95 instead of 905, which is less then 410.

Can you please suggest me a good way to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
(DATEPART(hour, sja.stop_execution_date) = 4 and (DATEPART(minute, sja.stop_execution_date) > 10)
OR DATEPART(hour, sja.stop_execution_date) > 4
```

Answer (score 5):

Could cast as a time.

```
cast(sja.stop_execution_date as time) > '04:10:00.0000000'
```

Comment: Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Type time is not a defined system type.

Comment: I don't know why this didn't work. Works ok for me sql server 2008 R2 and 2014.

Answer (score 3):

Could use total minutes instead:

```
DATEPART(hour, sja.stop_execution_date)*60 + DATEPART(minute, sja.stop_execution_date) > 250
```

Or `CAST( AS TIME)` and compare:

```
CAST(sja.stop_execution_date as TIME) > '04:10:00'
```

Comment: First one is working. Thanks.  But CAST as TIME is not working

Answer (score -1):

Use format function instead of CAST:

```
FORMAT(DATEPART(hour, '2014-09-04 09:05:55'), '00')+
FORMAT(DATEPART(minute, '2014-09-04 09:05:55'), '00') > '0410'
```

Comment: Wasn't FORMAT introduced in SS 2012?